# The osculating sphere.

Tags: geometry, multivariable-calculus, differential-geometry

> Let $c$ be a Frenet curve in $\mathbb{R^3}$ with $\tau(s_0)\neq 0$. Then the surface of the sphere centred at point
>
> $$c(s_0) + \frac{1}{\kappa(s_0)}e_2(s_0) - \frac{\kappa'(s_0)}{\tau(s_0)\kappa^2(s_0)}e_3(s_0)$$
>
> which passes through the point $c(s_0)$, has point of contact with the curve at the point $s_0$ of the third order. This sphere is uniquely determined by these properties and is called the osculating sphere.

I would like to understand a certain part of the proof.

Let
$$m(s_0) = c(s_0) + \alpha e_1(s_0) +\beta e_2(s_0)+ \gamma e_3(s_0)$$
be the centre of this hypothetical sphere.

Now according to my book $r^{(i)}(s) = 0,\quad i = 1,2,3$ where

$$r(s) = \langle m-c(s), m-c(s) \rangle$$

This is do not understand.
I started to consider $(m-c(s))-(m-S(s))=S(s) - c(s)$ where $S(s)$ in the arc created by the intersection of the line between the center of the sphere and $c(s)$ by the sphere and found that

$$(S-c)(s) \text{ has order of contact 3 at } s = s_0 \iff (S -c)^{(i)}(s_0) = 0 i = 1,2,3$$

Now I feel like I am nearly there.

> Could someone show why 
>   $r^{(i)}(s) = 0, i = 1,2,3$
>    is true mathematically?

Comment: Perhaps I'm confused: The defining condition for the osculating sphere $S$ is that $c$ and $S$ have order-three contact; that is, if the center of $S$ is $m$ and the radius is $r_{0}$, then $r(s) - r_{0}^{2} = \|m - c(s)\|^{2} - r_{0}^{2}$ vanishes to order three at $s_{0}$, which is precisely the condition that $r^{(i)}(s_{0}) = 0$ for $i = 1$, $2$, $3$.

Comment: Yes, I am trying to show it...algebraically. If that is possible. I was thinking of considering $ ||m - c(s)||^2 - \langle m-S(s), m-c(s)\rangle  =(m-c(s))\cdot(S(s)-c(s)) $ but it gets me no further!

Comment: I think I have a good idea of "order of contact", as in the curve's and the derivatives of the curves up to some order agree at $s_0$. I would like to rigorously show it(whatever that means).

Comment: The usual approach would be to expand $r(s) - r_{0}^{2}$ as a Taylor series about $s_{0}$: $r(s) - r_{0}^{2} = \sum_{i} \frac{r^{(i)}(s_{0})}{i!} (s - s_{0})^{i}$. Order-three contact means the first three terms of the sum vanish.

Comment: Yes,but how do you know $r$ has order-three contact? we know $c$ does, we know that S does. How can you say that $r = (m-c(s),m-c(s))$ does? That is what I am struggling to do.

Comment: As a function, the squared distance to $m$ cuts out each sphere centered at $m$ as a non-degenerate level set. At risk of repetition, it follows that a curve $c$ has contact to order $n$ (at $s_{0}$) with a sphere centered at $m$ if and only if $\|c(s) - m\|^{2} - r_{0}^{2}$ vanishes to order $n$ at $s_{0}$.

Comment: If you could expand that a little(up to you) and put it in an answer I will accept it.Sorry for being so dense. I am really enjoying the subject and just want to understand things as rigorously as possible. Thanks.

Comment: You're not being dense at all; it's subtle that the definition of contact is given for mappings, but sometimes applied to geometric objects, such as a curve and a sphere. :)

Comment: (Separately, I delayed this answer partly because I've been busy, but partly to let the bounty expire, since my answer doesn't warrant a bounty.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$\newcommand{\Reals}{\mathbf{R}}\newcommand{\Del}{\nabla}\newcommand{\eps}{\varepsilon}\newcommand{\Brak}[1]{\left\langle #1\right\rangle}$If $g$ and $h$ are smooth, real-valued functions defined in some open interval $(s_{0} - \eps, s_{0} + \eps)$ and if $N \geq 0$ is an integer, we say $g$ and $h$ have *order-$N$ contact at $s_{0}$* if
$$
g^{(i)}(s_{0}) = h^{(i)}(s_{0}),\quad 0 \leq i \leq N.
$$
This is a condition on *mappings*, not on *geometric objects*. To define "order-$N$ contact" of a curve and a hypersurface (such as a sphere), I assume you're using a definition of this type:

Let $f:\Reals^{n} \to \Reals$ be smooth, and assume $\Del f$ is non-vanishing on the level set $M_{c} := \{f = 0\}$, so that $M_{0} \subset \Reals^{n}$ is a smooth hypersurface.

A smooth curve $c:(s_{0} - \eps, s_{0} + \eps) \to \Reals^{n}$ has *order-$N$ contact* with $M_{0}$ at $c(s_{0})$ if the one-variable function $f \circ c:(s_{0} - \eps, s_{0} + \eps) \to \Reals$ vanishes to order $N$ at $s_{0}$, i.e., if
$$
(f \circ c)^{(i)}(s_{0}) = 0,\quad 0 \leq i \leq N.
\tag{1}
$$

It may be necessary (or desirable) to assume in addition that $c$ is "regular to order $N$" in the sense that $c^{(i)}(s_{0}) \neq 0$ for $1 \leq i \leq N$.

---

Assuming this framework suits your purposes, let $m$ be a point of $\Reals^{3}$, let $c$ be a smooth path, and let
$$
f(x) = \Brak{m - x, m - x} = \|m - x\|^{2}.
$$
The sphere of radius $\|m - c(s_{0})\|$ centered at $m$ has order-$3$ contact with $c$ at $s_{0}$ if and only if
$$
r(s) = (f \circ c)(s) = \Brak{m - c(s), m - c(s)} = \|m - c(s)\|^{2}
$$
equals $r(s_{0}) = \|m - c(s_{0})\|^{2}$ to order three at $s_{0}$. By (1), this means
$$
r^{(i)}(s_{0}) = 0,\quad i = 1, 2, 3.
$$

Comment: This answers it perfectly, thank you very much Andrew.